# incompatible type in overriding in third-party classes

Tags: scala, overriding, incompatibility

i want define a hibernate PersistentSet for scala mutable Set, but i have this compile error :-(

```
class MySet extends org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection with collection.mutable.Set[Any] {
  ...
}
```

error:

```
incompatible type in overriding
def empty(): Boolean (defined in class AbstractPersistentCollection);
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Set[Any]
 required: (): Boolean
  override def empty: mutable.Set[Any] = ???
```

if there's a good way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that would work in theory is defining `def empty()` in `MySet` with return type `mutable.Set[Any] with Boolean`. That should compile but it is impossible to find a reasonable implementation.

Alternatively you could define conversions between `mutable.Set[Any]` and `AbstractPersistentCollection` instead of using inheritance. You could do something like this:

```scala
class MySet private (private val set: mutable.Set[Any]) extends AbstractPersistentCollection {
  override def empty(): Boolean = set.isEmpty

  ...
}

object MySet {
  def empty(): MySet = new MySet(mutable.Set.empty[Any])
  def convert(set: mutable.Set[Any]): MySet = new MySet(set)
  def convert(set: MySet): mutable.Set[Any] = set.set
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but i can't use alternative solution, because i need `MySet` implements `mutable.Set[Any]` using this collection type in my entity `class MyEntity { val children: mutable.Set[ChildEntity] = new mutable.HashSet[ChildEntity] ...` and hibernate xml mapping `... <set name="children" collection-type="MySetType"> ...`